# Scrolling a list over a fixed element

Tags: javascript, css

I want to have a fixed container (a leaflet map) that a list with informations about the selected map item can be scrolled over.

I came up with this
https://jsfiddle.net/m5ntbyxs/5/

My list, that can be scrolled over the map, should start at the bottom of the screen and able to scroll up until it reveals all its content. I am using a `translate` to position the list further down on the screen. When no item is selected on the map, the list should scroll back down and not be visible. Just setting the `transform: translateY(100vh)` does only work, when the user has not previously scrolled up the list. Then the amount the user would have scrolled the list, would still be visible.

But it has another problem: it uses `fixed` layout, which takes the container out of the flow so it can not live properly in an app shell that also displays a title bar and nav bar.

Is there a way to achive this kind of effect without fixed element?

jQuery is **not an option** to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

made it work like so:

html :

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="menu"><h1>div.menu</h1></div>
    <div class="map">
      <p class="title">div.title</p>
      <div class="out" id="scroll">
        <li class="empty"></li>
        <li>a line of text</li>
        <li>a line of text</li>        
        <li>a line of text</li>
        <li>a line of text</li>
        <li>a line of text</li>
        <li>a line of text</li>
        <li>a line of text</li>
        <li>a line of text</li>
        <li>a line of text</li>
        <li>a line of text</li>
        <li>etc...</li>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="down"><p>div.down</p></div>
</div>
```

css :

```
  body {
    background-color: darkslategray;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
  }

  .box {
    color: gainsboro;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
  }

  .menu {
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 1px;
    padding: 10px 0 0;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    order: 1;
    &>h1 {
      border: solid 1px;
    }
  }

.map {
  display: block;
  background: teal;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 10 10 auto;
  order: 2;
  &>.title {
    position: absolute;
    border: solid 1px;
    background: teal;
    margin: 0 1%;
    width: 98%;
    padding: 16px 0;
    font-size: 24px;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  &>.out {
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 98%;
    margin: 0 1%;
    display: block;
    border: solid 1px white;
    z-index: 1;
    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none;
    }
    &>.empty {
      content: "";
      margin: 0;
      height: 90%;
      margin: 5px;
      border: solid 1px;
      position: realtive;
      background: none;
    }
    &>li {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 5px;
      border: solid 1px;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
  }
}
.down {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  order: 3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But that is not the behaviour I want. The list itself is deliberately not overflow auto, so that it expands itself to fit it's content. What should happen, if the list gets long, that the user is able to scroll it all the way over the map and back down.

Comment: Right. I made an edit.
Still uses overflow: auto/scroll but if the items in the list change, it should follow, no?

Also JQuery isn't an option but are you using js/other js modules?

Comment: Not a bad idea, the trick with the first item set to 100%. Altough it should let touch events through then, so that the element behind it gets the touch events. You codepen seems to scroll the list over the top and bottom divs. Is this a mistake?

Comment: Yes and no, I'm trying other things as well.

For items to get the touch events you could play with the z-index.
Like make the z-index of the empty div one level less than the map items but the rest of the list one level more. (empty div{z-index: 0}, map item{z-index: 1} list{z-index: 2} for exemple)